# Visual Studio Intellisense only operates on the current Startup Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

Visual Studio Intellisense is bugging out and only works on my current startup project.
I'm in the process of building a multi-project solution and as of earlier today Visual Studio decided that Intellisense would stop colour coding and providing information about code that I hover over with my mouse.
this is happening in all files within the solution apart from the single one in my current Startup Project.
I'm unsure whether the fact that that file is inside the startup project is important or not or what at all caused the bug to begin the first place.

I've been searching around for a while and tried just about every 'solution' that has come up.
I've changed the relevant settings off and on again.
I've deleted the dynamic .suo file in the hidden .vs folder.
I've reopened the files, visual studio, updated, made sure intellisense wasn't doing something in the background.
Apparently this bug can be caused by a corrupt .ncb file that lives in the solution directories, but I've failed to locate a file with that extension anywhere.
I'm also not using any extensions or such that mess with Intellisense's operation.

Are there any other possible things to try (hopefully not reinstalling) or just continue writing code in black and white?

[Intellisense working:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpfET.png)

[Intellisense not working:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrXvW.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to delete the `.vs` folder and clean the `%temp%` folder, this will reset Intellisense to the default state.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check your intellisense setting in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++:
[image]

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-intellisense?view=vs-2022) is a document about intellisense in C++. Hope it can help you.

If it doesn't work you can try to Reset all setting in Tools > Import and export settings. Or try to repair visual studio in visual studio installer.

If the above methods don't work, maybe you can only try  to reinstalle visual studio.